# Is it possible to get all arguments of a SCSS mixin, akin to JavaScript?

Tags: sass

In JavasSript, we can get arguments like this:

```js
function ab(a,b){
    console.log(arguments[0],arguments[1]);
}
ab(1,2);
// 1 2
```

I want to know if there is any way to get SCSS `@mixin` variables as a list just like how we can do it in JavaScript?

```
@mixin ab($a:1,$b:2){

@debug arguments; // stuff like this

}
```

Comment: Looks like it can be done with "arbitrary arguments" using a standard argument but with 3 trailing docs (similar to JS but the other way around) - see the [SCSS documentation on mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#taking-arbitrary-arguments) for more info.

Comment: that is close  : (,  but still not what I need.
I need  an arguments list that I can use it in "each" to do some @debug stuff.
And I need every variable to be optional

Comment: Looks like I didn't quite catch that the 3 dots are _leading_ (for e.g. `$args...`), not _trailing_ (for e.g. `...args`).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this?

```
@mixin grid($flex) {
    @if $flex {
        @include flex;
    } @else {
        display: block;
    }
}

@include grid(true);
```

Comment: I guess nope  :(
what I need is a arguments list that I can use it in "each" to do some @debug stuff

Comment: i think that is not possible, scss not is a complete development environment